# Homebrew, xCode 6.4 and boost

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, homebrew

I have a strange problem and can't figure it out. I have installed home brew and brew installed boost.

In the Xcode I add search header paths */usr/local/Cellar*, in the build setting I add .dlyb files.

Once I try to compile some example code I get warning/suggestion to replace in boost's headers **#include**  with **#include "boostFile"** brackets with quotes.

Any ideas why this is happening ?

Maybe I am doing something wrong, I'm not sure.

Thanks for any input.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Brackets are for standard libraries, quotes are for other libraries (such as boost). This rule is not applied to objective-c.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I am aware of that. But compiler complains about the quotes and brackets in the BOOST's header files and wants me to replace them with quotes. I'm not sure how to fix it.